# Ansible with_first_found errors

Tags: ansible

Ansible version: 2.9.6

I'm running the below `include_vars` task:

```
- name: Testing first found
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "vars/{{ myvar.split('-')[0] }}/{{ myvar.split('-')[1] }}.yml"
        - "vars/{{ myvar.split('-')[0] }}/{{ myvar.split('-')[1] }}-{{ myvar.split('-')[2] }}.yml"
      skip: true
```

Note that the value of `myvar` in this case is `hello-world`. The file vars/hello/world.yml exists, so there should be a match on the first item/file above.

When I run this I get the error: `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "No file was found when using first_found. Use errors='ignore' to allow this task to be skipped if no files are found"}`

However, if I comment out the above task to look like this:

```
- name: Testing first found
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "vars/{{ myvar.split('-')[0] }}/{{ myvar.split('-')[1] }}.yml"
        # - "vars/{{ myvar.split('-')[0] }}/{{ myvar.split('-')[1] }}-{{ myvar.split('-')[2] }}.yml"
      skip: true
```

Then the first file is found as expected and the vars are loaded.
I know that the second item in my `with_first_found` will give an error, since I only have 2 elements in `myvar` and I can't do a split [2]. But Ansible shouldn't be trying to even evaluate the second line since that's the point of with first found.

Just to test, I changed the split task a bit on the second line to use the element at 1 again:

```
- name: Testing first found
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "vars/{{ myvar.split('-')[0] }}/{{ myvar.split('-')[1] }}.yml"
        - "vars/{{ myvar.split('-')[0] }}/{{ myvar.split('-')[1] }}-{{ myvar.split('-')[1] }}.yml"
      skip: true
```

This also passed

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this works, I don't know why though:

```
- name: Testing first found
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - "vars/{{ myvar.split('-')[0] }}/{{ myvar.split('-')[1] }}.yml"
    - "vars/{{ myvar.split('-')[0] }}/{{ myvar.split('-')[1] }}-{{ myvar.split('-')[2] }}.yml"
```